# Using Java mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am using Java mail API to send a mail using `smtp.gmail.com` as host. When I use the below code and enable TLS it works fine but if I disable it, it's throwing `Must issue a STARTTLS command first` error.

```
       mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

What does it mean? So to connect to Gmail I should set this flag always? And also to connect to any mail server should we always enable secure connection (TLS or SSL)?

Comment: That's mail server settings. Its required for gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GMail smtp server seems to require TLS authentication. (See [here](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?rd=1#ts=1665018,1665144)). Which means that the server will reject your query if you do not enable TLS.

So yes, to connect to *GMail* you need to enable TLS. For a general mail server there usually is no need.